# Unexpected Drool error while making changes in the rule sheet

Tags: drools, rules

I am working with rule sheet maintained in an excel file in an application build on spring framework. Rule sheet contain some keys.
I am attaching the screenshot of the excel file to give you a better idea.

[image]

[image]

For some testing purposes, I want to move the keys in the 'PROD' column to the 'STAGE' column. When I do that, the application fail to deploy on jboss. It gives following error:

```
16:04:01,809 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'paymentApprovalService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: [8,9]: [ERR 101] Line 8:9 no viable alternative at input ''[22,9]: [ERR 101] Line 22:9 no viable alternative at input ''[35,9]: [ERR 101] Line 35:9 no viable alternative at input ''[48,9]: [ERR 101] Line 48:9 no viable alternative at input ''[61,9]: [ERR 101] Line 61:9 no viable alternative at input ''[74,9]: [ERR 101] Line 74:9 no viable alternative at input ''[87,9]: [ERR 101] Line 87:9 no viable alternative at input ''[100,9]: [ERR 101] Line 100:9 no viable alternative at input ''[113,9]: [ERR 101] Line 113:9 no viable alternative at input ''[126,9]: [ERR 101] Line 126:9 no viable alternative at input ''[139,9]: [ERR 101] Line 139:9 no viable alternative at input ''[152,9]: [ERR 101] Line 152:9 no viable alternative at input ''[165,9]: [ERR 101] Line 165:9 no viable alternative at input ''[178,9]: [ERR 101] Line 178:9 no viable alternative at input ''[191,9]: [ERR 101] Line 191:9 no viable alternative at input ''[204,9]: [ERR 101] Line 204:9 no viable alternative at input ''[217,9]: [ERR 101] Line 217:9 no viable alternative at input ''[230,9]: [ERR 101] Line 230:9 no viable alternative at input ''[243,9]: [ERR 101] Line 243:9 no viable alternative at input ''[256,9]: [ERR 101] Line 256:9 no viable alternative at input ''[269,9]: [ERR 101] Line 269:9 no viable alternative at input ''[282,9]: [ERR 101] Line 282:9 no viable alternative at input ''[295,9]: [ERR 101] Line 295:9 no viable alternative at input ''[308,9]: [ERR 101] Line 308:9 no viable alternative at input ''[321,9]: [ERR 101] Line 321:9 no viable alternative at input ''[334,9]: [ERR 101] Line 334:9 no viable alternative at input ''[347,9]: [ERR 101] Line 347:9 no viable alternative at input ''[360,9]: [ERR 101] Line 360:9 no viable alternative at input ''[373,9]: [ERR 101] Line 373:9 no viable alternative at input ''[386,9]: [ERR 101] Line 386:9 no viable alternative at input ''[399,9]: [ERR 101] Line 399:9 no viable alternative at input ''[412,9]: [ERR 101] Line 412:9 no viable alternative at input ''[425,9]: [ERR 101] Line 425:9 no viable alternative at input ''[438,9]: [ERR 101] Line 438:9 no viable alternative at input ''[451,9]: [ERR 101] Line 451:9 no viable alternative at input ''[464,9]: [ERR 101] Line 464:9 no viable alternative at input ''[477,9]: [ERR 101] Line 477:9 no viable alternative at input ''[490,9]: [ERR 101] Line 490:9 no viable alternative at input ''[500,9]: [ERR 101] Line 500:9 no viable alternative at input ''[513,9]: [ERR 101] Line 513:9 no viable alternative at input ''[523,9]: [ERR 101] Line 523:9 no viable alternative at input ''[536,9]: [ERR 101] Line 536:9 no viable alternative at input ''
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: [8,9]: [ERR 101] Line 8:9 no viable alternative at input ''[22,9]: [ERR 101] Line 22:9 no viable alternative at input ''[35,9]: [ERR 101] Line 35:9 no viable alternative at input ''[48,9]: [ERR 101] Line 48:9 no viable alternative at input ''[61,9]: [ERR 101] Line 61:9 no viable alternative at input ''[74,9]: [ERR 101] Line 74:9 no viable alternative at input ''[87,9]: [ERR 101] Line 87:9 no viable alternative at input ''[100,9]: [ERR 101] Line 100:9 no viable alternative at input ''[113,9]: [ERR 101] Line 113:9 no viable alternative at input ''[126,9]: [ERR 101] Line 126:9 no viable alternative at input ''[139,9]: [ERR 101] Line 139:9 no viable alternative at input ''[152,9]: [ERR 101] Line 152:9 no viable alternative at input ''[165,9]: [ERR 101] Line 165:9 no viable alternative at input ''[178,9]: [ERR 101] Line 178:9 no viable alternative at input ''[191,9]: [ERR 101] Line 191:9 no viable alternative at input ''[204,9]: [ERR 101] Line 204:9 no viable alternative at input ''[217,9]: [ERR 101] Line 217:9 no viable alternative at input ''[230,9]: [ERR 101] Line 230:9 no viable alternative at input ''[243,9]: [ERR 101] Line 243:9 no viable alternative at input ''[256,9]: [ERR 101] Line 256:9 no viable alternative at input ''[269,9]: [ERR 101] Line 269:9 no viable alternative at input ''[282,9]: [ERR 101] Line 282:9 no viable alternative at input ''[295,9]: [ERR 101] Line 295:9 no viable alternative at input ''[308,9]: [ERR 101] Line 308:9 no viable alternative at input ''[321,9]: [ERR 101] Line 321:9 no viable alternative at input ''[334,9]: [ERR 101] Line 334:9 no viable alternative at input ''[347,9]: [ERR 101] Line 347:9 no viable alternative at input ''[360,9]: [ERR 101] Line 360:9 no viable alternative at input ''[373,9]: [ERR 101] Line 373:9 no viable alternative at input ''[386,9]: [ERR 101] Line 386:9 no viable alternative at input ''[399,9]: [ERR 101] Line 399:9 no viable alternative at input ''[412,9]: [ERR 101] Line 412:9 no viable alternative at input ''[425,9]: [ERR 101] Line 425:9 no viable alternative at input ''[438,9]: [ERR 101] Line 438:9 no viable alternative at input ''[451,9]: [ERR 101] Line 451:9 no viable alternative at input ''[464,9]: [ERR 101] Line 464:9 no viable alternative at input ''[477,9]: [ERR 101] Line 477:9 no viable alternative at input ''[490,9]: [ERR 101] Line 490:9 no viable alternative at input ''[500,9]: [ERR 101] Line 500:9 no viable alternative at input ''[513,9]: [ERR 101] Line 513:9 no viable alternative at input ''[523,9]: [ERR 101] Line 523:9 no viable alternative at input ''[536,9]: [ERR 101] Line 536:9 no viable alternative at input ''
    at com.ge.epay.helpers.BusinessRulesHelper.readDecisionTable(BusinessRulesHelper.java:65) [classes:]
    at com.ge.epay.services.pvt.PaymentApprovalServiceImpl.afterPropertiesSet(PaymentApprovalServiceImpl.java:193) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
```

I even tried to change the value in the environment column. I swapped the PROD to STAGE and STAGE to PROD, even then I got the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?
The strange thing is I recently the changed the of the keys in all the PROD rows. That file worked properly. But now when I am swapping the values, the application is not even deploying.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot see a "PROD" or a "STAGE" *column,* only such strings in one of the condition columns.

Comment: My bad. I meant the PROD and STAGE rows. I was trying to swap their values.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a case of the quotes Excel & friends prefer to use. Make sure that your strings are delimited using the quote character, ASCII code 0x22.

By default, I have (in Open Access) “abc” which is 
    e2 80 9c   61 62 63   e2 80 9d

Comment: I didn't get you. App was working fine with existing file. I tried to copy the contents of one cell into another. Will that change the delimiter? Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Also I changed the values earlier. That time I copied the values of keys from a web page into the excel and saved it. It worked fine.

Comment: I can't tell from an image. I'd need the first 20 lines of the spreadsheet causing the error exported as a CSV text.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was because of the different double quotes versions. incorrect: ”  correct: "

Comment: To me, only the comment from @Slavomir came to the rescue. Thank you, bro